# How to prevent the creation of user stored procedure name started with SP_ in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

We have a SQL Server 2000 database that has a number of databases

We need to ensure that the users are unable to create stored procedure with a name that starts with `SP_`.

What can be done in SQL Server 2000 to prevent it?

I do understand that this can be achieved in SQL Server 2005+ versions using a stored procedure facet.

Comment: SQL Server 2000 is waaaaay to old to support anything like that.... you will have to enforce this using code reviews and slapping your devs on the hands if they use `sp_` as the prefix. I don't think there's anything that way available way back when (last millenium!) SQL Server 2000 come out ....

Comment: You can't create trigger on a system tables in MSSQL so one possible way I see is to create Agent Scheduled Job to find `SP_` procedures in `sysobjects` table and deny execute permission from all users to disable them and/or send a list to devs.

Comment: 2000 fell out of even extended support last year. It's beyond time to upgrade.

Comment: That might be true..but ours is a non profit Org...and do not have enough money to upgrade in accordance with big company(Microsoft's) tricky version releasing strategy !